# FQL console throw "Ops" error

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have this FQL query

```
select uid, name, website
from user
where website != "" and uid in (
    select uid2
    from friend
    where uid1 = me()
)
```

I tested this query in the [FQL console](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/) a couple of months ago, and it worked fine. Now I try it again and I have this error:

[image: the error]

that can be translated in english like "An error occurred. We are working to solve it soon". I tried with different queries and no one work, all throw the same error. Someone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an unspecified version, Facebook doesn't allow to query some private parameters (like the websites). So my old query is not valid now.